# How to get the value of my label? i am using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this c# form program and i want to get my text label value for some reasons, can somebody help?

I already tried this
String name = myLabel.Text
String name = myLabel.Text.ToString

but it will display none.

```
conn = dbHelper.getConnect();
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select custID from customer where name = '" + custNameLbl /*this is where i want to get the value*/ + "'", conn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                custIDStorage = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()); //this is an int
                namename.Text = custIDStorage.ToString(); //this is a label
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: Well that's it. Have you correctly set the value/text in the first place? Did you set the Name instead of the Text?

Comment: this code will get the Text value of the label, at the moment the code executes. If the label changes thereafter, the value of the variable will not change.

Comment: this is a label not a textbox. Yes i have set it on my name already

Comment: Where exactly is the line of code you showed? where and how do you "display" it ?

Comment: i have edited the question and the code is in there

Comment: What is `custNameLbl`? Is that another Control? If so, you're missing `.Text`, so your query will be `... where name = 'System.Windows.Form.Label'`, you won't find any matching record, so the `while (dr.Read())` loop will never execute, so you'll never set the other Label's `Text` property. BTW you shouldn't have a loop there.

Comment: Also this is prone to SQL inejction.